# Why i cant see volume in Render but can in preview?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, volumetrics

Why I cant see volume in renders, just the light.

Preview looks ok, but render not. Not even in EEVEE or Cycles.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE. Please share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can take a look :).

Comment: Hello here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6864" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6864/)